# Flask messages displaying "Please log in to access the page"

Tags: python, html, flask

I am doing a flash message such that when the user is registered, it will display a message "User Registered Successfully!", but when I try to log in, it will display a message "Please log in to access the page" even though I am already logged in.
How do I go around the problem?

This is the Login Route:

```py
@bp.route("user_settings/login", methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.user_settings'))
    
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()

        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            return redirect(url_for("auth.login"))

        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get("next")

        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for("main.user_settings")
            return redirect(next_page)

    return render_template("auth/login.html", title='Log In', form=form)
```

This is the Register Route:

```py
@bp.route("user_settings/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(username=form.username.data, password_string=form.password.data, access_level=form.access_level.data)
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("User Successfully Registered!", "success")
        return redirect(url_for('main.admin_mid', mode="admin")) 

    return render_template("auth/register.html", title="Register User", form = form)
```

HTML Template

```html
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %} {% if messages %} {% for
    message in messages %}

    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      {{ message }}
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
    </div>

    {% endfor %} {% endif %} {% endwith %}
```

Comment: You need to check whether the validation check actually works. Do you know what path you're taking through your code?

Comment: I get this flash message pop up *after* the user has successfully logged in. Frustrating. But I think I have a problem with flash messages in that they are getting stored "somewhere" and never show up until finally a page is rendered. So in my case, I think the flash message was launched long before the user logged in, but the message never had a chance to clear. For example, I see this with password error login messages, they just all stack up until finally the user logs in and sees forteen messages that he has to click on.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@login_required` in your register route.

It should look like this.

Register route:

```py
@bp.route("user_settings/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(username=form.username.data, password_string=form.password.data, access_level=form.access_level.data)
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("User Successfully Registered!", "success")
        return redirect(url_for('main.admin_mid', mode="admin")) 

    return render_template("auth/register.html", title="Register User", form = form)
```

The `@login_required` prevents users from entering the register page, and therefore creating accounts when they're not logged in.